# Working of API keys in artifactory

Tags: artifactory

In Artifactory, I am using an API Key for connection and it was expired, will it lock out the user account, or it will only block the connection to Artifactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how your Artifactory server is configured. If [user account locking](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Security#ConfiguringSecurity-UserLockandLoginSuspension) is enabled then after multiple failing login attempts your account will be locked.
If this is not configured, you login attempts will simply fail.